# Parenthesis before the new operator - meaning?

Tags: c++, static, new-operator, multiple-inheritance

For a child class I have the following code:

```
class child1 : public parent {
public:
    static parent* function1(void) {
        return (child2*) new child1;
    }
    //...
};
```

`Child2` is a other class that inherits from the parent.

What is the significance of using the parenthesis before the new operator i.e. `(child2*)`?
What's the best way to explain what the function does?

Comment: I think that it doesn't have any meaning here, even (child2*) will perform a pointer cast. `new child1` will return a pointer of type `child1*`, then it will be convert to `child2*`, but eventually, it will become `parent*`. Since the function return type is `parent*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return (child2*)new child1;
```

That is a C-style cast. It casts the pointer from `child1 *` to `child2 *`

If you intend to cast this from one kind of pointer to another, you should use the dynamic_cast keyword instead.

```
return dynamic_cast< child2 * >( new child1 );
```

C++ provides several casts to make it obvious what kind of cast you intend. It provides dynamic_cast for polymorphic casting (i.e. - does have a vtable), static_cast for casting objects that are not polymorphic (i.e. - doesn't have a vtable), reinterpret_cast to tell the compiler to consider the bytes within the object as a different kind of object, and const_cast to cast away constness or volatile-ness (or cast into a const or volatile object).

Many C++ programmers will never use C-style casts since the syntax of it provides no clue what you intend.

You should also know whether child1 and child2 are related. One should be a derived class of the other. If not, the dynamic_cast will return a nullptr.

Answer (score 0):

parenthesis here only do a static cast to type Parent.

But here this will not compile since you cannot cast object of child1 to object of child2. 
You can use dynamic_cast to cast different type of objects ,but since child2 is derived from Parent & not from child1 this cast will retun a nullptr.

It will populate an error as
Error   1   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'child2 *' to 'Parent

You should cast in to the type Parent.

Comment: The example does compile.